# How to make dynamic amchart with db connection?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, diagram

I need to draw dynamic chart for call answers and attempts. Database will update at every 1 minutes and then chart also update. I want to draw this diagram using amchart. But I don't know how to make db connection for dynamic charts. If anyone know about dynamic amcharts and db connection. Please upload a full code for it.

Here is sample diagram. But it is static diagram: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have developed the chart with dynamic values,in which i am getting data from MS ACCESS DB,I have developed it with ASP.NET using C#.

What you have to do is,
From the Code behind side Call the

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "amchart('" + graphresult + "');", true);
```

Here "graphresult" is my JSON string which contains data which i want to display in graph,"amchart" is name of function of javascript which resides at UI side,which contains amchart.

There is property called "dataprovider" in amchart now what you have to do is,you have pass argument of javascript function (here its 'graphresult') to your dataprovider of AMCHART,but make sure you are converting that data using `JSON.parse`,bingo your work done.

For any help please feel free to ask.

Thanks,
Sagar